# Is there any way to get direct video download link from YouTube and which work on another devices for long time?

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to get direct video download link from YouTube and which work on another devices for long time? I tried a lot of third parties softwares to generate the direct download links but after a short time these links dead. May be YouTube changes some parameters in the direct download url. I am trying this for my own channel, to offer direct download for my videos from YouTube at my website, so I need direct download links for each video.

Comment: If it's hard then please let me know any other solution with vimeo, dailymotion .... something to get the direct download link which I can use at my website to download videos directly with one click

Answer (score 0):

One of the [benefits](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6308116) of YouTube Red is the ability to download videos for up to 30 days on supported devices. This is the only official way I am aware of to download videos offline. According to the [YouTube Developer Policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies), you are not allowed to make content available for offline playback, so I would be cautious of these third party services.

One solution would be to upload the video to YouTube for normal online playback, and upload a copy of the video file somewhere else (ex. Google Drive or on your website) so that users can download from this alternate location.

Comment: I have a website where I will show the images of some good quality videos from YouTube, so when the users will click on any of the Image the video should be auto download in their PC, MObile or tab. I wan for the users just click on a button and the video starts download